# how to remove a body and a shape from a Space

Tags: python, pygame, physics, pymunk

I am making a game in python using pygame for the visual interface and pymunk to simulate the physical collisions between the ennemies and everything works just fine but now i want to remove the enemy bodies when they die (get to 0 health), so i used `pymunk.Space.remove(space, enemy.shape)` and `pymunk.Space.remove(space, enemy.body)` and so far everything works , when the enemy dies he disappears but the problem is once the image disapeared the pymunk "bodies" that process collision still persist which then blocks the other enemies. Also i dont wan't to just once they die move their bodies out of the map as i'm worried about it causing lags > see the photos

[image: All the ennemies when they just spawned]

[image: player hitting the enemies]

[image: enemies can't come closer / blocked]

[image: code]

Comment: Don't post screenshots of the code, post the code.

Comment: couldn't use the ```py when i'm posting images , or at least dont know how

Comment: I'm not talking about images but the code. Paste it and use ``` around it

Comment: It seems like you use a bit strange way to remove the bodies. Normally you would call `remove` on the space directly: `space.remove(enemy.shape, enemy.body)` instead of the roundabout way you do.

Comment: Removing the shape and body from the space will ensure that neither the shape nor body is included in any further collisions (in that space). Did you maybe just forget to also stop drawing the removed enemies?